# Vlookup When Target Column Has Multiple Text

Tags: excel, string, indexing, vlookup

I'm having trouble formulating this Vlookup.  I've searched and came across what I think may be solutions, but they don't seem to be working for me.  So I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible.

What I have is a word (lookup value) "Resin" and I want to search my database to return a 4 digit code.  So this particular code is 2821 and "Resin" Plastics Material and Resin Mfg is found in my table array.

Since Resin is included in that string of text, I would like for it to return the 2821 code.

Is this possible.  I've attached screenshots for assistance.

[image: Excel screenshots]

Answer (score 0):

Try matching it with a wildcard:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&P4&"*", 'SIC Code'!A4:C1211, 2, 0)
'        ^^^    ^^^                       ^?
```

But here I assumed that in the worksheet `SIC Code` the codes (`2821`) are in column 2 (`B`) and the name (`"Resin Plastics Material"` and `"Resin Mfg"`) are in column A. You might need to adjust according to the actual layout of the `SIC Code` worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try [here](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/) or [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/) read about MATCH&INDEX combine.